# Cors in Java Spring

Tags: java, angular, spring, http

I am adding this to my controller:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
@RequestMapping(value="/api")
public class CasaVendaController 

    @DeleteMapping("/casas-venda/{id}")         
    public Boolean deleteCasaVenda(@PathVariable("id") int id){
         this.casaVendaRepositorio.deleteById(id);

         return true;
    }
```

In my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, I have this:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login",             

                "/api/corretores").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().cors();

        http.addFilterBefore(JwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }
```

when I try to perform a delete to: http://localhost:8080/api/casa-venda/52. The browser complains of cors not being enabled. I am using Angular by the way. I doesn't get throught even the options method.

Answer (score 0):

Next bean will help you a lot

```
 @Bean
    fun corsFilter(): CorsFilter {
        val configuration = CorsConfiguration()
        configuration.applyPermitDefaultValues()
        val source = UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource()
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration)

        return object : CorsFilter(source) {
            override fun doFilterInternal(request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse, filterChain: FilterChain) {
                response.apply {
                    this.setHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN, request.getHeader("Origin") ?: "*")
                    this.setHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_METHODS, "POST, PUT, PATCH, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE")
                    this.setHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS, "${HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION}, ${HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE}")
                }
                when (HttpMethod.valueOf(request.method)) {
                    HttpMethod.OPTIONS -> response.status = HttpStatus.OK.value()
                    else -> filterChain.doFilter(request, response)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was not cors. Both Firefox and Chrome output cors issue on the console. But in reality was 404.

My endpoint is:

```
 http://localhost:8080/api/casa(s)-venda/52
```

I found out the problem using postman. In postman I was getting a 404 http status. That is very strange; on the browser I get 403 and in Postman 404.